# PhoneGap Native App issues

Tags: cordova, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to make a native app with the help of phonegap in dreamweaver cs5.5 but by hitting 'Build and emulate > Android' my emulator is giving

> Error: Attemtpting to call cordova.exec() before
>   'devicerready'.Ignoring.

can any one suggest me the correct way or point out mistakes in my code for reference the code is here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYPaF/).

Answer (score 0):

This error coming up sometimes can mean you're using the iOS version in an Android application.

Be ensure that you are using the appropriate version of **phonegap-1.7.0.js(or cordova-1.x.0.js).**

Each platform uses a different version of the file.